# Blow Back through carbs

Tags: kawasaki

I have a 1976 Kawasaki Z750 L3.
When i try to start the engine it is blowing the fuel & air back through the air filter rather than sucking it into the engine.
Any idears why this is.
Thanks all

Comment: Have you checked the timing?

Comment: And I believe Mike is asking about cam timing, not ignition timing.

Comment: Could be either - seen someone thrown over the handlebars from kickstarting a single when the advance/retard lever was left in advance....

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 remember when most of us nearly spilt our beers as a newbie asked what the advance/retard was for (he drove one of the jap imports) and was told that if you were an “advanced” driver you pushed the lever right, but for less competant drivers to keep it left... the howls of laughter....